# Note Taking App Hacked?

Tags: wifi, android, vulnerability, appsec

I am using the note taking app Color Note ([www.colornote.com](http://www.colornote.com)) on my mobile phone that is using Android 7.1.1 to take some notes (old device). I am not using their cloud sync capability, and my email/any personal accounts aren't connected to this app. I opened a note I was recently using to find that some text was inserted and saved to this note, text that I have absolutely no recollection of entering...

This text was a string of some whole words/sentences (eg. "see you later"), some repeated letters/nonsense (eg. xnvnbnmcmnnv) followed by a string of emojis, so there's little chance that this was inputted via pocket dialing/texting. Based on when the note was last edited/saved, I recall I was in a gym with secure wifi, but potentially sharing the network with strangers who were also there. I was using the wifi at the time, but as mentioned, this note app functions without internet and isn't connected to any cloud service.

Is there any chance that this text was entered via a security vulnerability in either my phone, the app, or the network that I was using?

Comment: *"Is there any chance ..."* - given how bugs and vulnerabilities work one cannot 100% exclude this as an option. But there are fare more likely explanation, as were given in an answer (pocket fumble).

Comment: So, someone with the advanced hacking ability to be able to hack into an arbitrary phone and remote control it, took that power to ... "scribble" on a single note and not take over the whole phone or use your banking app or take over your email? That's not likely.

Comment: "so there's little chance" was the opposite of the conclusion I expected you to arrive at after that description!

Answer (score 21):

It sounds like this is a pocket fumble. Predictive text would explain the coherent words, then the random letters all around the same area of the keyboard (where one might hold a phone when putting in your pocket), then emojis from predictive text again or your emoji keyboard if the spacebar was swiped.

Comment: Not to mention the voice dictation keyboard button.

Comment: water on the screen can also produce similar results. Alternatively, some prankster could have picked up the phone and tapped in some rubbish.

Comment: @barbecue Your last hypothesis seems unlikely, a normal prankster would surely write something more "interesting".

Comment: Don't forget about young children. They can be quite malicious unintentionally.

Comment: That also sounds like something I could reproduce half asleep in the morning.